# Java video manipulation library

Tags: library, video, java, video-editing

I'm searching for a Java library that allows me to do some video manipulation like splitting a video in many parts and converting it into some other formats.

I've found out that there are already some libraries like Xuggler but they are no longer under active development or maintained.

Can someone tell me which library I can use for accomplish my task or how can I build my own wrapper for ffmpeg?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend **[JAVE](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/jave/index.php)**.

> The JAVE (**J**ava **A**udio **V**ideo **E**ncoder) library is **Java
>   wrapper** on the **ffmpeg** project. Developers can take take
>   advantage of JAVE to transcode audio and video files from a format to
>   another. This description is taken from [here](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/jave/index.php).

JAVE supports (some examples):

- transcode an AVI file to a MPEG
- convert a WAV audio file to a MP3 or a Ogg Vorbis
- separate and transcode audio and video trackseparate and transcode audio and video tracks
- resize videos

I and my friend have used this library to build our project (part of course assignment), [ami-converter](https://github.com/meisyal/ami-converter), a desktop-based multimedia converter. With this library, we can convert original format of audio and video into another format. You might wonder the audio and video codecs that supported by JAVE, audio and video attributes, and anything else. I suggest you to read the [documentation](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/jave/manual.php).

Something that I don't know about JAVE is splitting a video in many parts, like you said before. At least, JAVE supports video format conversion.

The latest version of JAVE is released on April, 15 2009 (very old). I think it's still good library, though.